# Using anything but Testflight, how do I get iOS GameCenter Sandbox to appear on my father-in-law's phone?

Tags: ios, testing, game-center, sandbox, crashlytics

**Edit for emphasis:**

I live on the East coast and my father-in-law is on the West coast. He's a coder himself, from way back, though he's never developed for OSX or iOS.

I want him to join my testing group for my iOS game.

Apple has managed to make Testflight even worse and more unreliable than it used to be, so that's just not an option. And I say this because I tried it first, and four days later I'm *still* waiting for who-knows-what to be approved before I can distribute it. On the flip side, Crashlytics got the app on his phone within a half hour of downloading the plugin.

So: I can use Crashlytics to get my game on his iPhone, but it's a head-to-head game that relies on the Game Center Sandbox mode. His phone isn't develoment enabled, so the Sandbox options don't appear for him in settings.

How do I get the Sandbox options to show up on his phone?

Suggestions to use Apple's TestFlight are not an acceptable answer to this question. This question is specifically about how to enable these features without using TestFlight.

At the time of writing, the Crashlytics distribution process beats Apple's hands down: you don't have to wait through an inexplicable "review period", you don't have to crawl through arcane configurations for testers and builds and profiles and who's internal and who's external and etc etc, and best of all the app is available to distribute as soon as you compile it in XCode. *No export process at all*.

So, no, suggestions to use Testflight won't do. The only exception is if the only way to enable the GameCenter sandbox is to wrangle the first distribution through Testflight, and then do all the rest through Crashlytics. If so, so be it. But I'm ***really*** hoping someone's found another way.

**Edit for to be clear I'm not paid by Crashlytics:**

I'm not married to Crashlytics either, though! If there's a different method that's superior--and *not* Testflight--please suggest it!

Comment: Use TestFlight - after the app is installed through TestFlight a new setting for enabling Sandbox will be visible in Settings -> Game Center

Comment: Sorry Martin, I should have made clear how completely *not* an option Testflight is. I've edited the post to emphasize it. Hey people: Martin's not an idiot, I didn't say *anything* about wanting to avoid Testflight in the original post. It was a reasonable suggestion at the time.